# Import function from sibling module

Tags: julia

I have a package named MAIN. Inside the src folder I have the files:

```
src/
    MAIN.jl
    utils.jl
    models.jl
```

Inside MAIN.jl I have the following:

```
module MAIN

include("models.jl")
include("utils.jl")

end
```

The content of utils.jl is:

```
module utils
export foo
function foo()
    return 1
end
end
```

Then I want to use foo function inside a function in models.jl file.
Now I have the following:

```
module models
using ..utils

export bar
function bar()
   return foo()
end


end # module
```

But when I run `import MAIN`, I get the following error: `LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: utils not defined`.

So, in this setting, how can I import the foo function into the `models.jl` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of your problem is wrong order of `import` calls. `import` statements are evaluated sequentially, which means that `utils` module is undefined when you evaluate `models.jl` file. To fix this use the following sequence of imports:

```
module MAIN

include("utils.jl")
include("models.jl")

end
```